# 'Replace' changes entire src and not just the ending.. why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Situation:
I have ten gray divs (each with an image and text) as buttons. I want the buttons to have a darker text and darker image when active. When the active button is clicked I want it to deactivate. I also want it to deactivate when another button becomes active.

Problem:
When I replace the ending on the image sources, it changes the complete source on the images to the same as the active one... which changes all the other images to the same icon.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/messedUP90/gtf1dk0m/

Warning:
The jsfiddle shows the problem I am having with all the other images changing to be the same but for some reason the active image does not change color. It works fine in Dreamweaver so I am not too concerned about that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 300;
    $("[id^=pport]").click(function () {
        var src = $('.butt', this).attr('src');
        if($(this).hasClass('highlight')){
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
            $('.butt', this).attr('src', src.replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));
        }
        else{
            $('.butt').removeClass('highlight');
            $('.butt').attr('src', src.replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));
            $('.talk').fadeOut(x);
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
            $('.butt', this).attr('src', src.replace(/_light(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_dark$1'));
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is as you describe - you are changing the `src` of every icon to be the `src` of the one you have clicked, just swapping `light` with `dark`.

I.E. early on you set `var src = $('.butt', this).attr('src');`

At no point do you then re-set the variable `src` to anything else.

You then `$('.butt').attr('src', src.replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));`

This sets the `src` attribute of all elements with the `butt` class to the light version of the clicked icon.

That's where your problem lies...

Instead of simply trying to change the images in one go, you need to loop over the full set:

```
$('.butt').each( function( index ) {
    if ( $(this).attr('src') ) {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace(/_dark(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_light$1'));
    } 
});
```

Fiddle (working but with the same light / dark limitations as yours) here: http://jsfiddle.net/gtf1dk0m/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.butt').removeClass('highlight');
```

removes the `highlight` class from every element with the `butt` class. Likewise for the attribute replacement. You need to use `$(this)` instead.

Comment: the jsfiddle not showing the color change makes it more confusing. When the button is active it is not just the text that is black. the icon is black as well. That line of code is there so that the icon goes back to gray when another button is selected and that one turns black.

does that make sense? I know that is the line that is wrong... but i cannot make it correct.